# Deploy Play application locally

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I am aware of at least two local options to deploy Play apps, this is, either copying the whole thing and running play start, or exporting a war to run it as part of another app server.

I've also used the deploy mechanisms for gae and heroku. Very neat.

However, what I want to do is:

- deploy locally to my servers (there will be a bunch of them that receive the same copy, behind a load balancer).
- run just play with netty, so no war into tomcat/jboss/you name it
- do NOT deploy the source code, git files, etc.... Just the mimimum necessary (precompiled, config, templates I guess, public dir, ...)

Is there a command or option that I've missed in play to do this? Maybe exporting a war and running it from a different play server, if that makes sense? Or am I going to find out what is needed and not after a precompile and copy over only that?

**EDIT:**

The accepted answer is what I was looking for, but is not available on 1.2.x. Eventually I created my own script, where the most important bits are:

1. run play precompile
2. Copy the *conf/, precompiled/, public/, lib/* and *app/views/* directories to the location where you want to deploy (my script does a tar.gz of that and uncompresses it there).
3. run play start -Dprecompiled=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is for Play 2, not Play 1.

Run `play dist` to generate a zip that you can copy anywhere and run.  [More details...](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ProductionDist)

Comment: This is exactly what I want, only that I'm on 1.2.5, and seems not supported.

Comment: Oh whoops.  Sorry.  I don't know how to do that with Play 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can either deploy with the sources or as a war.

The most convenient way to deploy is to just fetch it from your vcs. See [Best deployment strategy for PlayFramework applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526735/best-deployment-strategy-for-playframework-applications) , answer of cdegroot for a discussion of that strategy.